# `fitsvm() got multiple values for argument 'c'` error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm

I have datasets that have more than `2000 rows` and `23 columns` including the `age column`. I have completed all of the processes for `SVR`. Earlier, I used the `SVR` model with default values. Therefore, I was unable to find the best best accuracy for `r_scored errors`. So, now I need to modify my code to find the best combination of parameters that outputs the highest R_squared value. To perform the best result I search using the following values for the parameters.

```
c = [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
Gamma = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]
Epsilon = [0.01, 0.1, 1]
```

But I am facing errors in the following two lines:

```
parameter['r_squared'] = fitsvm(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, c = c[0], gamma = Gamma[0], epsilon = Epsilon[0], axis = 1)

parameter.sort_values('r_squared',ascending=False).head()
```

The errors are:

```
fitsvm() got multiple values for argument 'c'
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Make fake dataset
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data= np.random.rand(2000,22))
dataset['age'] = np.random.randint(2, size=2000)

# Separate the target from the other features
target = dataset['age']
data = dataset.drop('age', axis = 1)

# train_data, train_target = data.loc[:1000], target.loc[:1000] - alternate naming scheme
X_train, y_train = data.loc[:1000], target.loc[:1000]

# test_data, test_target = data.loc[1001], target.loc[1001] - alternate naming scheme
X_test,  y_test  = data.loc[1001], target.loc[1001] 

X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(1, -1)

print(X_test.shape)


c = [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
Gamma = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]
Epsilon = [0.01, 0.1, 1]

c_,Gamma_,Ep_ = np.meshgrid(c,Gamma,Epsilon)
parameter = pd.DataFrame({'c':c_.flatten(),'Gamma':Gamma_.flatten(),'Epsilon':Ep_.flatten()})



def fitsvm(c,gamma,epsilon,X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    SupportVectorRefModel = SVR(C=c,gamma=gamma,epsilon=epsilon)
    SupportVectorRefModel.fit(X_train, y_train)
    R_Sqr = SupportVectorRefModel.score(X_test,y_test) 
    return R_Sqr

np.random.seed
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

s = StandardScaler()
dataset, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True) 

X = s.fit(dataset).transform(dataset)

X_train, y_train = X[:100], y[:100]
X_test, y_test = X[1001:], y[1001:] 

parameter['r_squared'] = fitsvm(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, c=X[0], gamma = X[1], epsilon = X[2] , axis=1)

parameter.sort_values('r_squared',ascending=False).head()
```

Comment: Why you set `c=X[0]` (and `gamma = X[1]`, for that matter)? These are *parameters*, and they should not have anything to do with your data `X`. Probably you meant to write  `c=c[0]`, `gamma=Gamma[0]` etc??

Comment: Dear mentor, `parameter['r_squared'] = fitsvm(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, c = c[0], gamma = Gamma[0], epsilon = Epsilon[0], axis = 1 )` but still have the same errors that is `fitsvm() got multiple values for argument 'c'` @desertnaut